# How to point on 2D / 3D space on a pre-allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

I memory optimized a code I have for embedded use. It works well but the result of this is that I got a lot of 1D, 2D and 3D mallocs and frees in the middle of functions that slow down the execution time.

For several reasons, I decided to modify the way I was doing it. I want to allocate all the memory I can with a single malloc at the start of my execution and just point the correct memory space where each array needs to be.

For info, I execute this on x86 for now so I don't any memory space issues. I declare my arrays this way:

```
unsigned char *memory;
memory = (unsigned char *)malloc(MYSIZE*sizeof(unsigned char)); 

type* p1;
p1 = (type *)((int)memory + p1_offset);

type** p2;
p2 = (type **)((int)memory + p2_offset);
for (int i=0 ; i<p2_height ; i++)
{
    p2[i] = (type *)((int)p2 + p2_width*sizeof(type));
}
```

While it works well for my 1D pointer, it returns me a segfault for my 2D pointer declaration. I checked my offsets and they are good compare to the memory pointer. As I'm not experienced with this way of declaring my pointers maybe I'm misunderstanding something here so I would be pleased if someone can explain me more about this technique !

Comment: in C, the returned value ;from malloc() and family of functions is a `void *` which can be assigned to any pointer,  and adding a cast can create problems when program maintenance is performed and makes debugging more difficult.  Suggest removing the cast from any malloc returned value

Comment: unsigned char is the same size as a signed char and `sizeof( char)` is defined as 1, so makes absolutely not effect on the value of the parameter passed to malloc().  to help declutter the code, remove the `* sizeof(unsigned char) expression from the call to malloc

Comment: what is 'type'?   it would be much better to have : type memory = malloc( ...);  and 'type' seems to be the same as 'int', given the posted code.  Why obscure the data format?   what are the values of `p1_offset` and `p2_offset` ?  it that defined in bytes, integers, or 'type`?  It is difficult to debug without knowing what is being manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re declaring p2 as a pointer to an array of pointers, not a pointer to a flat two-dimensional array.  You’re also (edited for clarity:) initializing `p2` with a garbage integer, then casting it back to a pointer and dereferencing it.

**Edited to add example code:**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Boilerplate to turn this into a MWE: */
#define MYSIZE  1024U
typedef double elem_t;
static const size_t p1_offset = 0, p2_offset = 512;

/* Our buffer will hold W 1d elements and X*Y 2d elements. */
#define W   64U
#define X   32U
#define Y   2U
typedef struct {
  elem_t array1[W];
  elem_t array2[X][Y];
} spaces_t;

/* Test driver: */
int main(void)
{
/* sizeof(unsigned char) is defined as 1.  Do you mean to allocate an
 * array of MYSIZE bytes or MYSIZE elements of type?
 */
  spaces_t * const memory = malloc(sizeof(spaces_t));
  if (!memory) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  elem_t* p1 = memory->array1;
  elem_t* p2 = (elem_t*)(memory->array2);

/* Never cast a pointer to int.  It's not even legal.
 * Why does this assertion succeed?  Why are memory and bad_idea
 * equal, but memory+1 and bad_idea+1 different by the size of both
 * of our arrays combined, minus one byte?
 */
  const uintptr_t bad_idea = (uintptr_t)memory;
  assert( (uintptr_t)(memory+1) - (bad_idea+1) == sizeof(spaces_t) - 1 );

/* Let’s initialize all the arrays.  No segfaults? */
  size_t i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < W; ++i) {
    *p1 = (elem_t)i;
    assert( memory->array1[i] == *p1 );
    ++p1;
  }

/* This is a lot faster when X is a power of 2: */
  for (i = 0; i < X; ++i)
    for ( j = 0; j < Y; ++j) {
      *p2 = (elem_t)(100*i + j);
      assert( memory->array2[i][j] == *p2 );
      ++p2;
    }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Yes there is: `p2[i]` is a dereference.  In any case, I posted an example now.

Comment: yes, but this is not a dereference of an `int`. `p2` is of type `type**`.

Comment: The problem is that p2 was initialized with the malformed expression, `p2 = (type **)((int)memory + p2_offset);` and contains garbage.  The best-case scenario at that point is a segfault; this could instead have led to silent memory corruption.

Comment: Another problem I have is that I work with a simulator that put all the malloc in the heap (I can have 3Mo) and all the static declarations in the stack (some ko). That's why I need to use a lot of mallocs for my arrays. And I use ints, floats, doubles, chars ... Some are 1D, some 2D, some 3D ... So if I read you, it's simple if all the memory is assigned as 1D but as soon as there are some 2D arrays in it it becomes a lot more touchy to do. I will keep this and try to do some things. Thanks.

Comment: mch: I see now the line of my answer you were pointing out to me, and it was unclear.  I’ve rewritten both that and my example of pointer arithmetic.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: It’s not that much more touchy.  A 2-dimensional array in C is really just a one-dimensional array under the hood.  You’ll notice I cast it to `elem_t*` and walked it with `p2`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `type** p2;` is a pointer to pointer, it has nothing to do with 2D arrays.

Instead, declare a pointer to a 2D array:

```
type (*p2)[x][y];
```

If you don't like to de-reference the 2D array as `(*p2)[i][j]`, then simply drop the innermost dimension in the declaration:

```
type (*p2)[y];
```

Now you can de-reference the 2D array as `p2[i][j]`. This trick works because `p2[i]` gives you pointer arithmetic based on the pointed-to type (an array of j type items), same as for any other pointer.

---

Also the cast from pointer to (signed) int is obscure and unsafe. For every case in the code where you do this, keep char type, calculate the offset and then cast it to `(void*)`. Example:

```
p2 = (void*)(memory + p2_offset);
```